Missing category in an interaction in emmeans, can I obtain the global marginal means for a level of a factor?
I have a dataset with measures coming from two environments from five different cities. On one of those cities we could not get measurements for one of those environments. When running emmeans I get the expect non estimated marginal mean for that environment from that city. See below:
 environment city_key emmean    SE  df lower.CL upper.CL
 R           C          3.20 0.472 210    2.266     4.13
 U           C          2.98 0.472 210    2.047     3.91
 R           K          4.61 0.609 210    3.408     5.81
 U           K          3.13 0.677 210    1.794     4.46
 R           M          3.85 0.666 210    2.534     5.16
 U           M        nonEst    NA  NA       NA       NA
 R           T          1.93 0.518 210    0.904     2.95
 U           T          1.95 0.509 210    0.952     2.96
 R           V          2.78 0.354 210    2.080     3.47
 U           V          3.32 0.879 210    1.586     5.05

However, I also want to obtain the marginal means coming from just the environments, but since I am missing one of those, one of the environmental results turns out as a non estimate. This is how emmeans works, from what I read.
 environment emmean    SE  df lower.CL upper.CL
 R             3.27 0.231 210     2.81     3.73
 U           nonEst    NA  NA       NA       NA

I am aware of the warning from emmeans ("Results may be misleading due to involvement in interactions"), and that a solution would be to remove the interaction between my two factors (already tried, and it works, but...), but it seems to me the biological significance of the interaction and its interpretation is important.
Mostly, the reason why I want the results is due to the standard error and the confidence intervals, which I am not sure how to manually calculate for marginal means.
Is there a way to get emmeans to output a result, despite the obvious hole in my data? Or a way for me to manually calculate the marginal means? Or are there alternative solutions?
Besides eliminating the interaction in my model. I tried predict_response from ggeffects, using margin=marginalmeans and margin=empirical, but these results diverge and I am thinking marginal means are the results I want. I have also tried and successfully obtained the marginal means manually by simply calculating them from the predicted values, but I don't know how to calculate the standard errors or confidence intervals from them--and while on this topic, would any of this be different if I was using a mixed model?
I did not include anything to reproduce my results since I believe my question to be straight forward. If you're interested in the number of my observations, here is a table for the number of observations per category (and why I have non estimates for city_keyM:environmentU):
   city_key environment   obs
   <fct>    <fct>       <int>
 1 C        R              25
 2 C        U              35
 3 K        R              13
 4 K        U              10
 5 M        R              15
 6 M        U               0
 7 T        R              23
 8 T        U              22
 9 V        R              72
10 V        U              16


Without any code examples, or even better, a reproducible example, it is difficult to say what's going on and how to help.

I don't like it that you put in obs = 0 rather than obs = NA in your example data table. You need to be careful to represent the situation.

@RussLenth I understand. Maybe I should have been more explicit. That table isn't an example, it's a summary of how many observations (or rows)  I have in my database. It was there to show simply that for that specific city and environment I have no data (or there's NAs). It's rather imbalanced give the nature of the sampling.

@DMenG Ah, I see. My bad for not reading carefully

Well, you can't have your cake and eat it too. You have a missing cell, and that means you can't estimate that cell, and that means you can't estimate a marginal mean for environment U.
It sounds like you were able to get "answers" from some other software; and that they disagree. That's because there is no right answer when you have that missing cell.
What you can do is estimate the marginal means using only the cities for which you have complete data. Obviously, it is your obligation to report that you made that choice.

Thank you! I came here expecting pretty much this answer, but as I am not a mathematician or experienced in statistics, I wanted to know if there was more that I wasn't aware of it was a quirk of the function I was using. I did not want to remove data from my analysis, but its likely I might have to do it.
